zsh alias does not complete fully if not sourced once a day
vi ~/.zsh
alias k='kubectl'
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl k
alias kga='k get all,ingress'

If I do not source .zsh every day it does not take into account the ingress part of the kga alias. So the kga alias does complete but without showing the ingress part if I do not source the file once i login. Once logged in and file is sourced it does take into account the ingress part. I do not need to source the file every time for the ingress part of the kga alias to be visible.
I'm thinking to just add a line which shall source the file but I guess its just pure syntax here which is wrong.
Probably it doesn't like the comma there between all and ingress and when i source it, it does get the comma right.

What exactly do you mean by "every day"? Is this about the date? You need to source again at midnight? Or is about every boot, so you need to re-source after rebooting and logging in? Or maybe each terminal? Please clarify. And what is the vi ~/.zsh line? Is that part of your zshrc file?

Every time i exit/logoff my system i have to source it for it to function properly and then it works for the rest of the time i'm logged in.
My aliases are in the .zsh file.

Please [edit] your question and explain this. Make sure to explain what this .zsh file is and how it is sourced. Are you not sourcing it from ~/.zshrc? Have you tried just adding . ~/.zsh into your ~/.zshrc file?

No idea what .zsh is (just got to use some already made env. to work with) but sourcing it is the answer. Yes that's true.

"the kga alias does complete but without showing the ingress part if I do not source the file" that's likely because there is an earlier alias definition for kga - for example provided by this ohmyzsh kubectl plugin

Thanks, This is the real answer!

If you have some sort of personal configuration file that isn't standard, such as this ~/.zsh you mention, of course you need to source it manually each time you log in. To make this happen automatically, you can simply stop using this file and add the aliases and completion commands to your ~/.zshrc file.
Alternatively, just tell your ~/.zshrc file to source this ~/.zsh thing. Add this line to your ~/.zshrc:
. ~/.zsh

Save the file, and from now on, each time you open a new terminal, ~/.zsh will be sourced automatically.
